# Powershell script required domain username and password to be invoked

Tags: powershell

I have written a validation script with few tests and the script run locally on each machine with help of a tool. But for running only below script part successfully the domain username and password to be invoked.

Can anyone help me adding username and password to invoke below script ( eg: username : oim\test , password : test@123 )

```
if (($ImageName -like "*devel*") -or ($ImageName -like "*hosted*"))
    {
        #$ADE1 = Invoke-Expression ('C:\ade\bin\ade.exe | select-string -pattern "begintrans"') | out-string ; $ADE = $ADE1.trim().split("")[1]
        Invoke-Expression ('C:\ade\bin\ade.exe | select-string -pattern "begintrans"') > C:\Temp\ade_check.txt 
        $ADE1 = Get-Content C:\Temp\ade_check.txt | Select-String "begintrans" | out-string ;  $ADE = $ADE1.trim().split(" ")[1]


        if ($ADE -eq "begintrans")
        {
        $ADE = "ADE Installation Success"


        Add-Content $report "<tr>"
            Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=center><B>17</B></td>"
        Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=left><B>ADE</B></td>"
        Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Aquamarine'  height='30' align=left><B>$ADE</B></td>"
        Add-Content $report "</tr>"

echo "ADE = ADE Installation Success"

        }

        if ($ADE -eq $null){
        $ADE = "ADE Installation Failed"


        Add-Content $report "<tr>"
        Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=center><B>17</B></td>"
        Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=left><B>ADE</B></td>"
        Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'red'  height='30' align=left><B>$ADE</B></td>"
        Add-Content $report "</tr>"

echo "ADE = ADE Installation Failed"
        }

    }
    else
        {
        if (($ImageName -like "*simple*") -or ($ImageName -like "*BareOS*")){

        $ADE = "BareOS, ADE Not Installed"


        Add-Content $report "<tr>"
        Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=center><B>17</B></td>"
        Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=left><B>ADE</B></td>"
        Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Yellow'  height='30' align=left><B>$ADE</B></td>"
        Add-Content $report "</tr>"

echo "ADE = BareOS, ADE Not Installed"
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use **Invoke-Command** cmdlet instead. It has **-Credentials** parameter that you want. Like this:

```
$UserName='oim\test'
$UserPassword='test@123'
$Password = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $UserPassword -AsPlainText -Force)
$Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($UserName, $Password)
Invoke-Command  -ScriptBlock { & 'C:\ade\bin\ade.exe' | Select-String -Pattern 'begintrans' > C:\Temp\ade_check.txt } -Credential $Credentials -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

Comment: @SNair, you may want to mark my answer as an answer so it will help someone that's looking for similar solution. :-)